# How can I add a method to NSString in Swift so that it sets the value of Self?

Tags: swift, nsstring, subclassing

I understand that subclassing NSString is a bad thing, but I'd like to add methods to NSString in Swift so that I can sanitise the string, according to specific rules, before storing its value.

I thought perhaps I could do something really simple like this (no sanitisation in this example - I'm just trying things out at the moment:

```
import Foundation

extension String{
    func setString(setter:String) {
        self = setter
    }
}
```

This doesn't work though - 'self' is immutable.  From looking at the docs, this would be valid for an initialiser - but I don't necessarily want to call this code for all strings.

I can find my way around ObjC - but I'm fashionably late to the party for Swift. Any suggestions?

**Update**

So this is a more accurate representation of what I'm trying to do (and thank you to everyone who has helped so far)

```
import Foundation

@objc extension NSString {
    
    func sanitizedFilename() -> String {
        let invalidCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\\/:*?\"<>|")
            .union(.newlines)
            .union(.illegalCharacters)
            .union(.controlCharacters)
        return self.components(separatedBy: invalidCharacters).joined(separator: "")
    }
    
    func sanitizedString() -> String {
        var invalidCharacters = CharacterSet().union(.illegalCharacters).union(.controlCharacters)
        invalidCharacters.remove("\n")
        invalidCharacters.remove("\t")
        return self.components(separatedBy: invalidCharacters).joined(separator: "")
    }
    
    mutating func sanitizeFilename() {
        self = self.sanitizedFilename() as NSString
    }
    
    mutating func sanitizeString() {
        self = self.sanitizedString() as NSString
    }

}
```

If I remove the NSString stuff - keep it as String then it builds, but I can't have @objc and hence I can't use it from Objective C.  If I put the NSString stuff in then self is immutable.

I have a feeling that this is a really easy fix for someone who actually knows what they're doing, and that I should probably put my head in a bucket.

Comment: Do you mean `NSString` or `String`? They are not aliases of each other in Swift.

Comment: In the title you mentioned `NSString` but the example shows `String`. As @Sweeper mentioned these are not the same.
If you really need `NSString`, then using `NSMutableString` is an option. If you are looking for `String` itself, then add the `mutating` prefix to the method.

Comment: My apologies - as I say, I'm new to Swift.  NSString is what I want, because this will be passed back to Objective C code that already exists (why not ObjC then? Well, I want to start future proofing myself!)

Comment: What I want is for the self to be updated with the string so that I don't have to sanitise each time the NSString is read. The sanitise should happen once when the value is stored.

Comment: That sounds like you have a property somewhere that requires the value to be sanitized before you assign it to that property. If so, the swifty solution is to a _property wrapper_ on that property that ensures the value is sanitized when you assign it.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of what you want to do exactly? Why do you want to replace `self`? Would it mean that there is a parsing issue before hand? You can also make a class method that would init with that clean value: `static func makeCleaner(_ string: String)`  etc?

Comment: "Before storing", why can't you add a `static func sanitize(string: String) -> String` and call it when you want to "store"? If you want to keep both value, you still can have a `lazy var` to your struct that will `return rawString.sanitized()` (and let it be this one only public)? I still think that your approach might not be the good one and might be better to use "alternative"

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to help you understand this.

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    
    // returns a new sanitized value (doesn't change anything in caller)
    func sanitized() -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
    }
    
    // Sanitizes self (changes the value of caller)
    // mutating is necessary when you need to modify self
    mutating func sanitize() {
        self = self.sanitized()
    }
}
```

Example usage

```
let test1 = "(Test)"
let output1 = test1.sanitized() // receive a new value
print(output1) // Test

var test2 = "(Test)"
test2.sanitize() // modify the caller, it has to be var (not let)
print(test2) // Test
```

Comment: That's great - but what I want is for the self to be updated with the string so that I don't have to sanitise each time the string (actually, it should be NSString) is read.  The sanitise should happen once when the value is stored.

Comment: In both of these examples, sanitizing is done only once no matter how many times you read it after being sanitized. I don't quite follow setting (NS)String into (NS)String. Please share a better example in your question so we can understand your use case better.